# ListView Not updating after RaisePropertyChangedEvent

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I have the following XAML

```
<Label Content="Player Name" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="2,0,2,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="White"/>
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2,2,2,2" Text="{Binding PlayerFirstName}"/>
<Label Content="Player Last Name" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="2,0,2,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="White"/>
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2,2,2,2" Text="{Binding PlayerLastName}"/>
<Label Content="Player College" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="2,0,2,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="White"/>
<ComboBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2,2,2,2"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Colleges}" DisplayMemberPath="CollegeName"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCollege}"/>
<Button Content="Add Player" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Width="75" Margin="2,2,2,2" 
                    Background="Blue" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    Command="{Binding NewPlayer}"/>
<ListView Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Margin="2,2,2,2"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Players, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="First Name" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding First}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Last}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="College" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding College}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Which is bound to my `PlayersViewModel` Class

```
public class PlayersViewModel : ObservableObject
{

    #region Variables
    private DataView _Players = Controller.PlayerView.GetData().DefaultView;
    private DataView _Colleges = Controller.CollegeTableAdapter.GetData().DefaultView;

    private string _PlayerFirstName;
    private string _PlayerLastName;
    private DataRowView _SelectedCollege;
    private long _PlayerCollegeID;
    #endregion 

    #region Bindings

    public DataView Players
    {
        get
        {
            return _Players;
        }
        set
        {
            _Players = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Players");
        }
    }

    public DataView Colleges
    {
        get { return _Colleges; }
        set
        {
            _Colleges = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Colleges");
        }
    }

    public string PlayerFirstName
    {
        get { return _PlayerFirstName; }
        set
        {
            _PlayerFirstName = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("PlayerFirstName");
        }
    }

    public string PlayerLastName
    {
        get { return _PlayerLastName; }
        set
        {
            _PlayerLastName = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("PlayerLastName");
        }
    }

    public DataRowView SelectedCollege
    {
        get { return _SelectedCollege; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedCollege = value;
            _PlayerCollegeID = _SelectedCollege.Row.Field<long>("CollegeID");
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("SelectedCollege");
        }
    }

    public ICommand NewPlayer
    {
        get { return new DelegateCommand(AddPlayer); }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    private void AddPlayer()
    {
        Controller.PersonTableAdapter.InsertPerson(_PlayerFirstName, _PlayerLastName, _PlayerCollegeID);
        Players = Controller.PlayerView.GetData().DefaultView;
    }

    #endregion

}
```

This all works great, except when I run the `InsertPerson` Query in my PersonTableAdapter (which works manually and I've proven to work from the program), The `Players` ListView doesn't update after adding a new entry.

Comment: Your collection doesn't appear to notify when an item is added or removed. Try throwing a `RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Players");` event in your `AddPlayer()` function.

Comment: It's raised in `Players` property

Comment: .....I'm dumb again. I didn't implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface in my `ObservableObject` Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what I did wrong.

**Always make sure you are Implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface in your `ObservableObject` Class**

Mine looks like this now:

```
public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChangedEvent(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```